# MySQL prepared statement not returning results java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

i have a simple stored procedure in mysql and am trying to call it from jdbc. i keep getting an empty result set. i've searched and tried several solutions on similar threads to no avail. note that table.quantity is not a fixed decimal, which is why i'm using double/BigDecimal.

the relevant columns in my table are:

```
quantity   DOUBLE UNSIGNED
orderTime  TIMESTAMP
```

and here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getTotal`( IN pSince TIMESTAMP, OUT pVolume DOUBLE UNSIGNED )
BEGIN
    SET pVolume = ( SELECT SUM( quantity ) FROM db.table WHERE orderTime > pSince );
END
```

i've also tried it like this:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM( quantity ) INTO pVolume FROM db.table WHERE orderTime > pSince;
END
```

neither seems to work when i call it like this:

```
CallableStatement lCall = getConnection().prepareCall( "{call getTotal(?,?)}" );
lCall.setTimestamp( 1, new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() - 600000 ));
lCall.registerOutParameter( 2, Types.DOUBLE );
lCall.execute();
ResultSet lResults = lCall.getResultSet();
lResults.next();
return lResults.getBigDecimal( 1 );
```

this returns an empty result set.

adding `lResults.beforeFirst()` throws a null pointer exception because the `lResults.rowData` is null. i've also tried `lResults.getBigDecimal( "pVolume" )` with the same result.

i've also tried:

```
ResultSet lResults = lCall.executeQuery();
lResults.next();
return lResults.getBigDecimal( 1 );
```

which throws a SQLException on `lResults.next()` because it says the call was an UPDATE and, therefore, doesn't have any results.

i suspect that i'm missing something in my stored procedure. any ideas?? oh, and i'm logging in as dev, not root. i checked the permissions and i can execute.

Answer (score 1):

Results from `CallableStatement` are retrieved directly through its (own) declared methods:

```
lCall.execute();
return lCall.getBigDecimal( 2 );
// do not forget to close the statement - try-with-resource
```

no need to call `getResultSet()` (from `Statement`).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/CallableStatement.html):

> The type of all OUT parameters must be registered prior to executing the stored procedure; **their values are retrieved after execution via the get methods provided here**.